# Take values from a buffer C++

Tags: c++, buffer

I want to take the first 8 bytes (64 bits) from a buffer and combine them into a large number to use later on in the program. I am getting the info in the buffer from a HDD and I want to use it.  I'm using Visual C++ 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two obvious ways you can do this. The first is mathematically:

```
const unsigned char* buffer;
unsigned __int64 iValue;

iValue = buffer[0]
     | ( buffer[1] << 8 )
     | ( buffer[2] << 16 )
     | ( buffer[3] << 24 )
     | ( static_cast<unsigned __int64>(buffer[4]) << 32 )
     | ( static_cast<unsigned __int64>(buffer[5]) << 40 )
     | ( static_cast<unsigned __int64>(buffer[6]) << 48 )
     | ( static_cast<unsigned __int64>(buffer[7]) << 56 );
```

You'd swap the bytes if you needed to convert the endianness of the data.

The other way is to copy the bytes directly - you can do it using a `reinterpret_cast` as shown in the other answer, but a "better" way is to use `memcpy`, e.g.:

```
memcpy(&iValue, buffer, sizeof(iValue));
```

Comment: I'm a little curious how `memcpy()` might be "better" than a proper cast... I believe the cast would handle endianness issues properly (assuming the underlying data actually makes sense under the re-interpretation, anyway)...

Answer (score 0):

if you have a char* buffer, and you want to store 64 bits, the simplest way would be:

```
char *buffer = "this is a test";
long long stored = *reinterpret_cast<long long *>(buffer);
```

and if you want to get your bytes back:

```
char *retrieved = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&stored);
```

Comment: In your example `buffer` is only 5 bytes long and so this would result in reading random memory beyond the buffer.